# Chrome Extension blocked from a rails API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors

I am just trying to talk with a REST api on a Rails site.
I am using a Chrome extension and javascript to make a CORSRequest.

I get this error whenever I  try to make a request:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://MYWEBSITE.com/api/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://mychomreextensioncode' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Here is my current code:

```
function makeCorsRequestLogin() {


  var url = "https://MYWEBSITE.com/api/login";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = text; //getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there\'s an error making the request.');
  };
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var user_name = document.getElementById("username").value;
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"user_name":user_name, "password":password}));
}
```

Elsewhere, in the past, people have said that this code solves it. But, I have no idea where this could would go.

```
# This is used to allow the cross origin POST requests made by confroom kiosk app.
  def set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = %w{GET POST OPTIONS}.join(",")
  end
```

I am only working in JS and HTML on a chrome extension. I do not have access to the ruby site. Can I solve this problem from only my end?

Comment: I said at the bottom that I have no access to the ruby server. And I asked if I could solve this issue from my end. As I understand your comment, the answer to that question is no. correct? @JaromandaX

Comment: sorry, I missed the "ruby" comment ... but then I also forgot you were talking about a google-chrome-extension - so, you **can** do what you need without access to the server - the key is your manifest.json file (I can't find the web page, sorry)

Comment: Thank you, i just added the server's URL to the manifest's permissions and it worked like a charm. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should define permission for your server domain in the **manifest.json**.

```
"permissions": ["https://MYWEBSITE.com/*"]
```

Also make sure you set the right protocol whether it's http or https.

Comment: Indeed, without access to the server this is the only solution.